# A simple way to apply a .gitignore file to all subfolders containing individual projects in the repository

Tags: git, gitignore, subdirectory

I have a Git repository containing a lot of subfolders, each of which is an IntelliJ IDEA project.

I have found a JetBrains `.gitignore` which ignores files in an IntelliJ IDEA project and I want to apply it to all such projects in these subfolders.

Of course, I can make a copy for each project, or leave it in the root folder and edit the patterns in the `.gitignore` file to match files in subfolders.

However, I am wondering whether there is a simpler way to do this rather than making copies or editing a long `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Can you post your .gitignore. You should be able to make it apply to all directories.

Comment: Are those files same for all projects?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Comment: @blami Yes they are.

Comment: Great, then you go ahead with my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore same set of files put that `.gitignore` file into root of your Git repository and prefix all lines that apply to all subdirectories with wildcard `/*/`. Same set of files will then be ignored in all subdirectories, with no need to update `.gitignore` when you add or remove subdirectory.

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the
>   pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the
>   particular .gitignore file itself.

So if you have following directory structure:

```
my_repo/
  .gitignore
  project1/
    foo.txt
    bar.txt
  project2/
    foo.txt
    bar.txt
```

And want to ignore `bar.txt` in all project directories then your `.gitignore` will be:

```
/*/bar.txt
```

Comment: You only need `bar.txt`. That will ignore it everywhere.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I think that was not the point of question. OP has set of constant files that appear in every single directory and he wants to ignore only those (that's how I read zis question). So ze don't necessarily want to ignore `project1/some/foo/bar.txt` but only `project1/bar.txt`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarfying

Comment: Though this is exactly what I mean in the question by "leave it in the root folder and edit the patterns in the .gitignore file to match files in subfolders", which is not what I am looking for, it seems it's the best approach that's currently possible.

Comment: @ShreckYe I understand but this is how `.gitignore` file works - it applies only to directory where it is and directories below (eventually overriding same rules from files in above directories). There are other options how to globally ignore files (e.g. `core.excludesFile` configuration option or `.git/info/exclude` file - see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description)) but those are specific to single user workflow and not pushed nor cloned with repo. So to answer your question completely - what I proposed is likely best what you can do with `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a script which will do that for you?

#### Bash

```
# Something like:

for i in $DIRECTORY/.gitignore; do
   cat "<my desired gitignore additional context>" >> .gitignore
done
```

Comment: If all the directories share files to ignore why not put them in a single top level gitignore then add specific ignores in project folders

Comment: From what i understood it not a single git project but multiple projects

Comment: @CodeWizard It is a single Git repository, but it contains many IntelliJ IDEA projects.

Comment: So, in this case, you can use a single global gitignore, why do you need multiple ones?